# Windows8.1 won't let normal user choose a specific input language

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard, input-languages

On my new Windows 8.1 box, I managed to configure an administrator user to use keyboard "Français - Belgique".  But when I use the exact same procedure for a user without administrator privilege, Windows 8.1 shows it the config menus but in the end uses another keyboard input method.  It seems that even if "Français - Belgique" is available, Windows cannot make use of it and the input method is either the second language that is used, or if there's no second keyboard, it automatically adds English.

Can someone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

Try providing **full permission** for your user to the following folders and check the reported issue

**C:\Windows\System32**

**C:\Windows\winsxs**

Right click on the folder and go to **properties > Security > Edit** and provide full permission to your user

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi vembutech,  I wanted to give it a try but even while being admin of this machine, I cannot modify permissions on these folders.  BTW it works ok on a different PC with the same effective permissions for normal users as on this one...